# PHP, GIT, Location for reusable components

Tags: php, git, composer-php, organization

Thanks for your attention, this is a question of organization, I work with PHP and GIT for version control. I use Netbeans IDE to program, GIT integrated (although I am still a rookie).

Normally, I follow the approach that Symfony2 specifies for organize the project files, but I use my own framework for my projects. 
The (main) question is: **Any component or code part which has its own version control must be located under the `/vendor/`directory?**

For example:
I have my project files in `src\Acme\ProjectX\`, also the utility package which use all my projects: `src\Acme\Util\`, and it is under the version control too (GIT).

and now let's remember the basic skeleton of a project based on Symfony or similar:

```
/app (application related elements)
/src (source code of the project)
/vendor (third party libraries)
/web (front end controller, the web directory, assets resources etc...)
```

So, Must be 'Acme\Util' included in the vendor directory? And, is necessary to use composer to declare the dependences?

In addition, the Utility package has a lot of classes but only few are used in projects. Must I remove those are not using by the project.

Summarizing, It will be nice if someone can contribute his knowledge for help me to represent an scenario like this.

I hope I could explained...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

#### Vendor directory

It's a good practice to separate external dependencies and the application code. If you are using Composer [you can change it to something else](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir).

#### Unused classes

Unused classes shouldn't matter if they aren't being loaded. They'll just take a bit of extra disc space.

It might be a good idea to separate the *Utility package* into multiple packages if you find yourself frequently using only a small part of it.

#### Dependency managers

It isn't *necessary* to use a dependency manager, but it sure does help. Having to install, configure and maintain everything manually (especially with many dependencies and sub-dependencies) would be a horror.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your recommendation is to use a dependency manager in projects which share code with each other, whenever possible.

In the case of the 'Util' package, you would include it in the vendor directory: `/vendor/Acme/Util/` but if I want to keep in the /src I should define that in the configuration of composer. If so, I think for now I'll leave it in /src. And now I'll see how I can work this way with my Netbeans IDE.

OK. Let's see if anyone can bring a little more knowledge and incidentally, that the debate could serve other programmers.

Thanks for your time

Comment: @MikeBau I'd make the *Utility package* a Composer package. Then it can installed & configured by Composer automatically (if it is defined as a dependency). It's up to you where you host these. See Composer docs for more info https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository